# dax filters producing different results

Tags: powerbi, dax

please can you let me know why these two measures produce different results? I am obv missing something simple to do with AND and OR. thank you.

```
measure 1 = CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( fct_core[colour] ),
    fct_core[type] = 1
        || fct_core[type] = 2
        || fct_core[type] = 3
        && fct_core[colour] = 5
        || fct_core[colour] = 6
        || fct_core[colour] = 7
        || fct_core[colour] = 8
)

measure 2 = CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( fct_core[colour] ),
    fct_core[type] >= 1
        && fct_core[type] <= 3
        && fct_core[colour] = 5
        || fct_core[colour] = 6
        || fct_core[colour] = 7
        || fct_core[colour] = 8
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages) misunderstanding.

If you put in appropriate parentheses, then these measures should be the same (assuming types only have integer values).

```
measure 1 =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( fct_core[colour] ),
    (
        fct_core[type] = 1 ||
        fct_core[type] = 2 ||
        fct_core[type] = 3
    )
        &&
    (
        fct_core[colour] = 5 ||
        fct_core[colour] = 6 ||
        fct_core[colour] = 7 ||
        fct_core[colour] = 8
    )
)

measure 2 =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( fct_core[colour] ),
    (
        fct_core[type] >= 1 &&
        fct_core[type] <= 3
    )
        &&
    (
        fct_core[colour] = 5 ||
        fct_core[colour] = 6 ||
        fct_core[colour] = 7 ||
        fct_core[colour] = 8
    )
)
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the order of operations in this example but parentheses resolved the discrepancy, thank you.

Comment: A || B && C || D is not equivalent to (A || B ) && (C || D) but rather to A || (B && C) || D, just like 1 + 2 * 3 + 4 is not equal to (1 + 2) * (3 + 4) = 21 but rather 1 + (2 * 3) + 4 = 11.